# Check Db column data

Tags: android, sqlite, if-statement, constructor, onclick

I want my Onclick method that is used used to insert data into a database to first check if data exist. If there is data, a toast message appears. how can I accomplish this. My OnClick is below. I just it to verify there is a username and password. If there is, the user receives a toast.

```
 @Override
public void onClick (View v) {

    rUsername = rName.getText().toString();
    rPasscode = rCode.getText().toString();

    RegDetails regDetails = new RegDetails();
    regDetails.setrName(bundleRegName);
    regDetails.setpCode(bundleRegCode);
    if(v.getId()==R.id.rtn_button){
        finish();

    }else if(v.getId()==R.id.reg_button){
        insertCredentials(regDetails);
    }
}
    private void insertCredentials(RegDetails regDetails){

        LoginDB androidOpenDBHelper = new LoginDB(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = androidOpenDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(LoginDB.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME, rUsername);
        contentValues.put(LoginDB.COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD, rPasscode);

        long affectedColumnid = sqliteDB.insert(LoginDB.TABLE_NAME_CREDENTIALS, null, contentValues);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Credentials Saved! Please login" + affectedColumnid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        sqliteDB.close();
        finish();
    }   

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sqliteDB.insert return long value on success and -1 on error. The long value indicates the row number for newly inserted row in db. You can check this return value and display toast accordingly.

Please look at the detailed explanation here, [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

In short, modify your code to be like this,

```
private void insertCredentials(RegDetails regDetails){

    LoginDB androidOpenDBHelper = new LoginDB(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = androidOpenDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(LoginDB.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME, rUsername);
    contentValues.put(LoginDB.COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD, rPasscode);

    long affectedColumnid = sqliteDB.insert(LoginDB.TABLE_NAME_CREDENTIALS, null, contentValues);
    if(affectedColumnid != -1){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Credentials Saved! Please login" + affectedColumnid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }else{
     // Display error dialog or smthg
     }
    sqliteDB.close();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read your database . If cursor.getCount() >0  thats mean data exists.

```
Cursor cursor = getDbEntries();
if( cursor.getCount() > 0 ){
   // data exists
}
else{
  // data doesnt exist
}
```